# php mysql while - loop while condition is the same

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a db that have this kind of structure:

```
name|color

paul|blue
mary|red
paul|green
joe |yellow
paul|purple
mary|orange
paul|white
etc |etc
```

What am I trying to achieve here is to list the colors associated with a name, something like this:

```
paul=blue,green,purple,white
mary=red,orange
joe=yellow
```

I was checking some examples and found this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM  mytable order by name";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['color'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

To be honest I just don't know how to go from this to what an I trying to achieve. How can I create a condition that will list all the color associated with one name and then jump to the next and so on?

Comment: you can use `group by` for grouping by name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(color) AS color
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name
```

[**See this fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e14f0/1) - **updated**

If you need to account for duplicates, use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT color)`. You can also include a custom `SEPARATOR`, but if you leave it out the default is `,`. So in your case you don't need to specify. Also, as can be seen in the documentation linked above, you can, if desired, order the colors in whichever way you see fit - although, note that the default order is ASC, so you don't need to specify that, either, unless you want to change it.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your insight, apparently I am not good enough. could you tell me what am I missing here:

$query="SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(color) FROM mytable GROUP BY name";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['color'];
 echo "<br />";
}

Comment: @pcapelo You need to add `AS color` to the `GROUP_CONCAT` select in order to use the variable `$row['color']`. See my updated answer - that should fix the problem. Also, it's none of my business but you should consider using `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of `mysql_*` - it is depreciated.

Comment: thank you again I will defenitely search into that, I still learning. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can do all with the SQL query:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT color ORDER BY color DESC SEPARATOR ',')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score -1):

thank you for pointing me into the right direction. I manage to gather more info and make it work with this:

```
$query="SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(color) FROM mytable GROUP BY name";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";  
echo "<td>" . $row['GROUP_CONCAT(color)'] . "</td>";  
echo "</tr>";  
}
```

Thank you again :)

Comment: That works, yes, but is not necessary. Simply add `AS color` to the select statement and you can call the column by that name - `color` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT(color)`

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, you should accept it and not copy it into a new answer.

Comment: I don't get it. what I did was to put everything together, sorry you didn't like it. Marks was credited and I post his contribution and the rest I was missing to make it work.

Comment: Technically, my answer has not been credited until you click the check mark next to it. Jeroen is simply pointing out that instead of accepting my answer, you posted your own containing a nearly identical solution.

Comment: Mark, I am sorry then, I did post your answer with the extra part that worked for me because I wanted to have everything in one place, and yes I have marked your answer as well, my apologies on that.

Comment: No worries @pcapelo, thanks. Glad we were able to get your problem solved :)

Comment: Thank you again Mark and Casimir, I have been improving my code,  thanks to the answer I got here.